# loading custom slider from NIB vs from code: no subviews present when loaded from code

Tags: iphone, ios4, initialization, subviews

I am trying to create a custom UISlider. I need to insert subviews (like a label) to self. I'm using the

```
[self insertSubview:_label1 atIndex:2];
```

method to do so. Everything works fine when I create my slider in IB and assign my PWSlider class to it.

However, if I try to create my PWSlider from code, there are no subviews present when I do my inits (adding my subviews).

For the init in code I override `initWithFrame`, for the NIB-case I tried both, awakeFromNib as well as initWithCoder - same result.

When I debug with

```
NSLog(@"subview count: %d", [self.subviews count]);
```

the result is that loaded from NIB I get 3 subviews, loaded programmatically I get 0.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is my own implementation of my custom UISlider... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I assume your PWSlider is inherited from UISlider and also assume you have code which is something like:

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)r {
  self = [super initWithFrame:r];
  if(self) {
    // add your subviews here, starting from index 0
  }
  return self;
}
```

Did you debug and check that your initWithFrame gets called?

Also, if you don't care at which locations your subviews are, use addSubview instead of insertSubview:atIndex:.

Comment: Yes, your assumptions are correct. The initWithFrame gets called and I do care where the subviews are inserted... Currently I'm using the slider from NIB file only. Thanks for ur suggestion! Other ideas?